# Inserting multiple labeled figures inside table?

Tags: tables, labels

I have been struggling with rewriting *MS Word* table which consists of 4 figures (Fig 2 - 5) into *LaTeX* environment (I need label all of the 4 figures because of references) - last part of the document I can't "solve".

Is it possible to do something like that

[image]

I haven't succeeded so far.

Or is it better to make 4 separate pictures and put them into the table (while removing the figures labels and label them all inside of *LaTeX* table instead?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried so far to achive the desired output?

Comment: Should the whole table also get a caption?

Comment: Do you also want to reference the sub-parts of the images? e.g. something like "see figure 1b)"?

Comment: @leandriis yes, the whole table should also get a caption as a "Table 1. Summary of nanomechanical experiments", while the pictures inside should be referred as pictures "Figure 2, Figure 3, ... , Figure 5". 

Yes, if it's possible, then it should be referenced as 2a) , 2b), etc. but this is not a condition.

Well, to be honest, it's not much, mostly nothing. Not that I haven't tried, but I had also issues with the row alignment. I'm not an advanced LaTeX user, mostly writing "raw" articles / texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following might get you started:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\setlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\newlength{\equationwidth}
\setlength{\equationwidth}{\textwidth-\imagewidth-4\tabcolsep}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\caption{summary of...}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\imagewidth} p{\equationwidth}}
\toprule
\thead{text here} & \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.9\equationwidth}r@{}} \thead{text} &\thead{eq.}\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
  \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,valign=t]{example-image}%
  \captionof{figure}{some image caption}%
  \label{image} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\equationwidth}@{}}%
      {\begin{flalign} 
        E' = ...&& \label{continuity_1}
      \end{flalign}}
      \\ \midrule
      {\begin{flalign} 
        E = ...&& \label{continuity_2}
      \end{flalign}} 
      \\ \midrule
      {\begin{flalign} 
        H = ...&& \label{continuity_3}
      \end{flalign}} 
  \end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

See table \ref{table} See figure \ref{image}
\end{document}
```

Here is an updated version with the rotated text:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newlength{\imagewidth}
\setlength{\imagewidth}{5cm}
\newlength{\equationwidth}
\setlength{\equationwidth}{\textwidth-\imagewidth-6\tabcolsep-2ex}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\belowdisplayskip=0pt
\caption{summary of...}\label{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{2ex} >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\imagewidth} p{\equationwidth}}
\toprule
&\thead{text here} & \begin{tabular}{@{}p{0.9\equationwidth}r@{}} \thead{text} &\thead{eq.}\end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\parbox[t]{2mm}{\multirow{10}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{some rotated text}}}
&  \includegraphics[width=\imagewidth,valign=t]{example-image}%
  \captionof{figure}{some image caption}%
  \label{image} &
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}p{\equationwidth}@{}}%
      {\begin{flalign} 
        E' = ...&& \label{continuity_1}
      \end{flalign}}
      \\ \midrule
      {\begin{flalign} 
        E = ...&& \label{continuity_2}
      \end{flalign}} 
      \\ \midrule
      {\begin{flalign} 
        H = ...&& \label{continuity_3}
      \end{flalign}} 
  \end{tabular}\\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

See table \ref{table} See figure \ref{image}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank You! I'm going to try it right now and let you know :)

Comment: Thank you! I think I got it (https://github.com/JKhay/LaTeX/blob/master/Table%201). One last question: how do I manage to get the vertical text into the table: "Mechanical properties" , "Adhesion", "Tribological properties".

Comment: @JoshE.: Oh, I overlooked the rotated text. I'll add an update

Comment: Update added. I just had a look at your code. Good job. One thing I however noticed is that the resulting table is quite likely too large to fit into the page. If you get a warning message such as "Float too large for page by ..." you will have to do some adjustments. either decrease the image size or switch to `longtable` in order to allos for a pagebreak.

Comment: Thanks. However, the text is crossing the Figure 1 description. Is it possible to put it next to it (left side). I tried changing the `\parbox` dimension (not that I know much about it), but it didn't work. Apparently, I can't leave the tabular space with the paradox. Instead of creating a new column, is it possible to put a "text box" on a page which position is defined by coordinates (A4 dimensions)? I know the table is slightly larger than the page :) I will adjust it at the very end :-). I changed the dimension due to better img visibility. I have updated _GitHub_ code.

Comment: I think that my intention is apparent, but this is the desired result :) https://imgur.com/a/HCyWinv

Comment: I have tried to use `textblock*`, but it doesn't work for some reason, because it moves the table on the next page, I though it would act like float not influencing the rest of the page content: `\begin{textblock*}{1cm}(1cm,7cm)\rotatebox{90}{Mechanical properties}   \end{textblock*}`

Comment: In your updated github code you did not add the third column as I did in m example.  This is why the rotated text overlaps with the figure caption. Personally, I would definitely use a dedicated column for the rotated text. If you prefer to try without, maybe you want to give the tikzmark and tikz picture overlay approach a try.